# Today widget iOS 11 update default height?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios11

what is the default height of **today widget extension**. iOS 10 it was **110px** Based on that we have designed custom table cell with height of **110px** to show only one cell and we have option **show more** to see remaining cell.

The code :

```
let version = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
//        print(version)
        if version >= 10 {
            self.extensionContext!.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(350))
        }

func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
        if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded{
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(0.0), height: CGFloat(350))
        }
        else if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact {
            self.preferredContentSize = maxSize
        }

    }
```

after iOS 11 update it seems default height has increased what could be the default height ?. still i am using Xcode 8.3.3 only.

iOS 11 show less and show more button not working properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing update in Height, It is still same.

According to[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html)

Kindly check **Design the UI Guidelines**

**NOTE:
Don’t specify a height for your widget that would require a user to scroll to see all its content.**

And change your code like below :

```
let version = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
//        print(version)
        if version >= 10 {
            self.extensionContext!.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayMode.expanded
          //  self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(350))
        }
```